# Positioning items in unordered list with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, list, css-float

I have a [demo](http://www.olmasigereken.com/demo2/). I want to align red arrows which are coming from javascript side left like in [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h4Rkj.jpg). But i couldn't figure out how do i do. If i add `float:left;` inside `.ikinciSol ul li a` block arrow goes left but dash and other parts become destroyed.

```
  function ytplayer_render_playlist( )
  {
    var arrOfListNodes = Array.prototype.filter.call(document.getElementById('mylist').childNodes, function (e) {return e.tagName === 'LI';});
    for ( var i = 0; i < ytplayer_playlist.length; i++ )
    {   
      var img = document.createElement( "img" );
      img.src = "track_arrow.gif";
      var a = document.createElement( "a" );
      a.href = "#ytplayer";
      a.onclick = (
        function( j )
        {
          return function( )
          {
            ytplayer_playitem = j;
            ytplayer_playlazy( 0 );
          };
        }
      )( i );
      a.appendChild( img );
      arrOfListNodes[i].insertBefore(a, arrOfListNodes[i].firstChild);
    }
  }
```

How can i modify these part? Or is there simpler way of doing it?

Answer (score 1):

Get rid of the img tag and modify your list element:

```
ul li {
   list-style-image: url("track_arrow.gif");
}
```

Comment: If i do it dash goes in front of tw

Comment: Thanks for your efford. But how can i give link to these images with javascript after your changes? Image links are came from javsscript already in my demo.

Comment: Are you really going to be using different images for list items?  It seems like unnecessary overhead when you can just declare it in the CSS.  If you insist on making it dynamic, you can change the property in javascript by modifying `element.style.listStyleImage = "url(foo.gif)"`

Answer (score 1):

You can replace the `div` with `span` tags, as you anyway set their display to `inline`. This seems to work, you can get rid of all the floats properties too :

[JSFiddle sample code](http://jsfiddle.net/2GkBa/)